# Unable to find why Order By is sorting correctly

Tags: sql

My data is ordering correctly, for the most part, however, there are some which are out of order. The totals of the bars is what is the descending order is supposed to be. But you can see CO and TX are out of order. Is there something wrong with the query? I am unable to find an answer.

```
select to_state,
       count(to_state),
       service
  from uscount
group by 1, 3
order by 2 desc
limit 10
```

[image: The sum of the stacked bars is what should be sorted by]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have multiple columns per state -- one for each service in the state.  If you want to order by the total for state, then one method is window functions:

```
order by sum(count(*)) over (partition by state) desc, state, service
```